# Get selectedvalues of multi-select list box

Tags: c#, list, select

I have got a list box in multi select mode which is data bound with 15 values from a database. I have this code to display the selected values of each item selected in the list box:

```
        foreach (var list in list_box.SelectedItems)
        {             
            MessageBox.Show(list_box.SelectedValue.ToString());
        }
```

Unfortunately, the correct amount of message boxes display but they only display the selected value of the first item in the list that has been selected.

Please can someone help me with this issue? I have been searching the net but I cannot find one example that works correctly!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I came back to this issue and solved it by doing this:

```
  foreach(int blah in multilistbox.SelectedIndices){

  MessageBox.Show(blah.ToString());

  }
```

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 1):

You should be pulling the value from your **list** variable not from the list_box object.

Comment: Thanks, I understand the logic now (very tired!). However, the message box is displaying System.Data.DataRowView?

Answer (score 1):

You're looping the selected items already.  Why not just call

```
MessageBox.Show(list.ToString());
```

Answer (score 1):

I think you may have a logic error in your code. You are looping through the `SelectedItems`, but your `MessageBox` is still using the `list_box` to display a value. How about this?

```
foreach (var list in list_box.SelectedItems)         
{                          
MessageBox.Show(list.ToString());         
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
foreach (var list in list_box.SelectedItems)
{             
    MessageBox.Show(list.ToString());
}
```

Comment: Thanks, I understand the logic now (very tired!). However, the message box is displaying System.Data.DataRowView?

Comment: [DataRowView](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.datarowview.aspx) - use the Items property to get the specific value you're looking for

Comment: How does this work? By putting a for loop inside the foreach loop? Sorry, I am unsure how to do this.

Comment: it would help if we knew what sort of object you bound your list_box to.  Can you edit the question to include a snippet where you do that databinding?

Answer (score 1):

can be done this way.

```
Int[] AllselectedIndex=ListBox1.GetSelectedIndices();
```